# Reading the dataset from a javaFX linechart

Tags: javafx, linechart

I am using JavaFX Linechart in an application. I would like to read X and Y axis of the graph from the display. I mean from the graph.
How can I do that?
 I would like to save the values in an ArrayList/ Array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for the _visual coordinates_ of each `XYChart.Data` in your `LineChart`, right?

Comment: The values of the `Chart` are already stored in a `List`. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe your question could be asking for either the *visual coordinates* of your data **or** the *real data used to plot the chart* I'm going to provide answers for both.

---

### Real Data

A `LineChart` extends from [`XYChart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html) which has a [data property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#dataProperty). This property contains an `ObservableList` of [`XYChart.Series`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html). Each `XYChart.Series` *also* has its own [data property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html#dataProperty). *This* property contains an `ObservableList` of [`XYChart.Data`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html). Each `XYChart.Data` has a [property for its X value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#XValueProperty) and a [property for its Y value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#YValueProperty). Access these properties to get the X and Y values used to plot the graph.

Since the chart already contains the data you're looking for in a collection there may be no need to add it to a separate `ArrayList` or array.

---

### Visual Coordinates

A `XYChart` (which again `LineChart` extends from) has [a X axis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#getXAxis()) and [a Y axis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#getYAxis()). These are of the type [`Axis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html) which provides the following method: [`getDisplayPosition(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html#getDisplayPosition(T)). This method takes as an argument the *real data* that was plotted on the axis. For example, if you plotted the point (4, 16) you'd get the display positions by:

- For the X coordinate: `chart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(4);`
- For the Y coordinate: `chart.getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(16);`

When using a `LineChart` (and most likely other charts but I've only tested it with a `LineChart`) these coordinates **are not relative to the `LineChart`**. Instead they are relative to a child `Region` that has a style-class of `chart-plot-background` (at least in my testing). Here is the code I used to test getting the visual coordinates. It creates a `LineChart` with an exponential function from [0-10] and adds `Circle`s to a `Group` stacked on top of the `LineChart` in the same positions as the plotted data.

*Note: I used the `var` keyword a lot which was added to Java 10. You'll either need Java 10+ to run this or you'll need to replace the `var` keywords with the explicit type*.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var chart = createChart();

        var group = new Group();
        group.setManaged(false);
        primaryStage.setOnShown(we -> addFadingCircles(group, chart));

        var root = new StackPane(chart, group);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Workshop");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private LineChart<Number, Number> createChart() {
        var xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("X");

        var yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("Y");

        var chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        var series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();

        for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, Math.pow(x, 2)));
        }

        chart.getData().add(series);
        return chart;
    }

    /*
     * This method assumes that "group" is stacked on top of "chart" and takes up the
     * same area in the scene-graph.
     */
    private void addFadingCircles(Group group, LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        var animation = new ParallelTransition();
        animation.setAutoReverse(true);
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        var plotRegion = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");

        for (var series : chart.getData()) {
            for (var data : series.getData()) {
                var xPos = chart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(data.getXValue());
                var yPos = chart.getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(data.getYValue());

                var scenePoint = plotRegion.localToScene(xPos, yPos);
                var groupPoint = group.sceneToLocal(scenePoint);

                var circle = new Circle(groupPoint.getX(), groupPoint.getY(), 10);
                circle.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);

                var fadeTrans = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), circle);
                fadeTrans.setFromValue(0.0);
                fadeTrans.setToValue(0.8);
                animation.getChildren().add(fadeTrans);

                group.getChildren().add(circle);
            }
        }

        animation.play();
    }

}
```

Running this code results in:

[image: GIF animation of circles stacked on top of LineChart's plotted data]

If your goal is to add things to the `Node` used to indicate plotted data it may be better to manipulate the [node property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) of the `XYChart.Data`, however.